# why does across work with coalesce only when inside a function?

Tags: r, tidyeval

Little tidyeval question, I've got this function:

```
coacross <- function(...) {
  coalesce(!!!across(...))
}
```

And then if I do something like this:

```
aa = tibble(a1 = c(NA, 1), a2 = c(2, NA), b = 3:4) %>% 
mutate(a_full = coacross(starts_with('a')))
```

Works like a charm. But if I do the same outside a function, I get an error:

```
aa %>% mutate(c = coalesce(!!!across(starts_with('a'))))


Error in `across()`:
! Must only be used inside data-masking verbs like `mutate()`, `filter()`, and
  `group_by()`.
```

What gives? I'm a bit lost here. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://github.com/tidyverse/funs/issues/54

Comment: Think the only way is to add a new mutate `aa %>% mutate(c = coalesce(!!!mutate(., across(starts_with('a')))))`

Comment: Thanks to both, now I understand a little bit better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've reached the obscure side of tidy eval programming :-/

The problem is that `!!!` is evaluated very early by the first verb that happens to support injection operators:

- In your first example, there isn't any injection in the `mutate()` call. Instead, `!!!` is triggered at the `coalesce()` call inside `coacross()`, and so the timing is correct.
- In your second example, `!!!` is triggered at the `mutate()` call. Injection is the very first thing that happens, which means that `mutate()` hasn't had time yet to set up the data-masking context that `across()` needs, and so the timing is too late.

To work around this the overlap between injection contexts must be removed. This is what you did by moving the `!!!` in another function. An alternative is to inject a call to `coalesce()` but that's rather ugly and very hard to understand:

```
aa |> mutate(c = !!quote(coalesce(!!!across(starts_with('a')))))
```

I prefer your `coacross()` solution.